# Pass variable from one script to another on same page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

All,

I've been struggling with this and I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong. I have a PHP file that has multiple scripts in it, including PHP and jquery sections. I'm trying to pass a PHP variable from the html Head section to the Body. Each are each in their own  php script section because I have a jquery script in between, also in the Head. Below is the relevant code. How do I pass the $reset_question php variable from the top section to the bottom section?

I just added the button "submit 3" to bring up the form I'm having problems with. Maybe something in my syntax?

```
<head>
<?php
  require_once('../connectvars.php');
  session_start();
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  // Clear the error message
  $error_msg = "";

  // other code that I'm not having a problem with

if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) {

  // Grab the user-entered log-in data
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));
  $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['first_name']));
  $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['last_name']));

  if (!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($email) ) {
    // Make sure someone isn't already registered using this username
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_database WHERE email = '$email' AND first_name = '$first_name' AND last_name = '$last_name'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
      // The username exists
      $query = "SELECT reset_question FROM user_database where email='$email'";
      mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

      // Confirm success with the user
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        $reset_question = $row['reset_question'];
      }
        exit();
      }
      else {
      // An account doesn't exist for this e-mail
        echo '<p class="error">All of your information was not recognized. Please complete the information correctly or sign-up to register.</p>';
        $email = "";
      }
    }
    else {  
      echo '<p class="error">You must enter all of the required data.</p>';
    }
$_SESSION['reset_question'] = $reset_question;
  }
}


// Insert the page header
require_once('../reference/header_sub.php');

// If the session var is empty, show any error message and the log-in form; otherwise confirm the log-in
if (empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
echo '<p class="error">' . $error_msg . '</p>';
// closing bracket is down below 
?>

// other code that I'm not having a problem with

//jquery script
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>

// jquery isn't having any issues that I can see

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="allcontent" style="position:relative;top:-20px;">

<?php
// Insert the tabbed navigation
  require_once('../reference/tabs_sub.php');
?>

<br />

<fieldset> 

<!-- html forms that I've not having problems with -->

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <table class="reset">
  <tr><td colspan="2" ><legend style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;height:25px;">Reset your password</legend></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="register" ><label for="first_name">First Name:</label></td>
  <td><input style="width:200px;" type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php if (!empty($first_name)) echo $first_name; ?>" /><br /></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="register" ><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label></td>
  <td><input style="width:200px;" type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php if (!empty($last_name)) echo $last_name; ?>" /><br /></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="register" ><label for="email">E-mail:</label></td>
  <td><input style="width:200px;" type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (!empty($email)) echo $email; ?>" /><br /></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit3" class="submit3"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">  
  <table class="answer">
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="remember" >Please answer the following question!</td></tr>   
    <tr><td class="remember" >What is: <?php $_SESSION['reset_question']; ?>?</td></tr>
    <tr><td ><input style="width:200px;" type="text" name="reset_answer" value="<?php if (!empty($reset_answer)) echo $reset_answer; ?>"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>

</fieldset>

<?php
} // closing bracket from above opening bracket
else {
// Confirm the successful log-in
  echo('<p class="login">You are logged in as ' . $_SESSION['email'] . '.</p>');
  require_once('/download.php');
}
?>

<?php
// Insert the page footer
require_once('../reference/footer.php');
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: So, did you try to use `$reset_question` in the bottom section? You got errors or what?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all the combinations that I can think of to pass from one to the other. When I use $reset_question it doesn't return any result. The $_SESSION['$reset_question'] is giving me a scream error and says that "$reset_question" is an undefined index.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your variable $reset_question only exists in the scope of the while loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $reset_question = $row['reset_question'];
    //....
}
```

Instead initialize the variable outside of the while loop.

```
$reset_question = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $reset_question = $row['reset_question'];
    //....
}
```

Comment: I just tried it with $reset_question outside of the while loop and still no luck. I did change it to $reset_question instead of $_SESSION['$reset_question'] at the bottom and it still didn't work.

Comment: I tried it with both $reset_question; and $reset_question = '': and neither fixed the problem.

Comment: To try to figure out what's going on you could hard-code the reset_question variable at the top of your code and then try to use it further down in the code. You need to figure out what part isn't working. Is the while loop not executing any code? Or what?

Comment: I've tried numerous combinations of both $reset_question; and $reset_question = '';. I'm either getting a completely blank screen or the following "Please answer the following question! 
What is: ?" with a the page never completely loading from localhost. I get the wheel of death.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable out of any brackets. Just in php script scope and you will get it anywhere down in file, nothing else is needed to pass (access) it in lower script.

Best place to declare/initialize it is before

```
$reset_question = 'Defaut Question';
if (!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($email) )
{
```

If you do not get anything in $reset_question in your conditions then you will get 'Defaut Question'

**Upadte :** One more try and i am sure you will get at least "What is Defaut Question?"
 write `$reset_question = 'Defaut Question';` just after `$error_msg = "";` as

```
$error_msg = "";
$reset_question = 'Defaut Question';
```

Comment: I've tried it everywhere that I can think of within the script and it's not working. I'm either getting a completely blank screen or the following "Please answer the following question! What is: ?" with a the page never completely loading from localhost.

Comment: Try now you will not get a blank screen. Now you will get at least "What is: Default question?"

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when I tried the above all I got was "What is: ?"

Comment: Sorry Sami. It still didn't work. I don't think it's a problem with my WAMP install but right now all I'm getting is the loading wheel on the page tab. It's still showing "What is: ?"